# Assigning a random value to an array

Tags: c, arrays, srand

I'm trying to

1. Get rid of the info in an array with 10 "spots".
2. Fill the array with (10) random numbers

My code till time

```
int main()
{
    int numbers[10] = { 0 };
    int randNumber = 0;
    int i = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        srand(time(NULL));
        randNumber = rand() % 10 + 1;
        printf("Random number saved in the array: %d\n", randNumber);
        i++;
    }

    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Assign the values to the array.

Comment: Alright, but if the random-function is outside of the for-loop. Will it not just create one random number? (atleast it does now when I have moved it outside). My intention for putting it inside the for-loop was to create a new random number each time the loop runs.

Comment: `srand()` does not _create_ the random numbers. `rand()` actually gives you the _random_ numbers.

Comment: `srand(time(NULL));` means "pick the pseudo random number sequence `#1474983934`" (`#1474983935` in the next second). Afterwards, `rand()` means "pick the next number in the selected sequence". If you always restart the same sequence and always pick the first number thereof, you always get the same number. Solution: move the `srand()` call outside the loop.

Comment: Do your numbers have to be in the range 1 to 10?  If so, you might want to start out by assigning values sequentially (`for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) numbers[i] = i+1;`), then do a [random shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) on the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you need to move the `srand(time(NULL));` out of the loop.

Otherwise, because, `time()` has a time granularity of 1 second, in a second, if called multiple times in the loop (*within a second, probably*), it will re-initialize the PNRG with the same *seed* and all the next call to `rand()` will give you the same *random* number.

Now, once you have the *random* numbers, you need to **assign** it to the each array member like `numbers[i] = randNumber;` inside the loop, but there's more to it. Your loop, at present is off by one. You need to change

```
  for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
```

to

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
```

to stay within bounds.

Answer (score 3):

Your array's size is 10, and this loop runs 11 times, causing an overflow. This will solve it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
```

Also remove the increasing of the loop's iterator, `i`, from inside the loop body. Remove the line:

```
i++;
```